# Center div inside 100% width container with dynamic width left and right floats

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

I want to have 3 divs aligned inside a container div, like this:

[[LEFT]       [CENTER]        [RIGHT]]

Container div is 100% wide (no fixed width), and center div should remain in center after resizing the container.

Left and Right DIV have no fixed width and need to expand/contract with the container. Center DIV does have a fixed width.

I have this:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div style="float: left; height: 50px;"></div>
    <div style="float: right; height: 50px;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; height: 50px; width: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is, the left and right do not show because there is no set width

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with pure CSS. You need to use JavaScript. In the example below Middle div is fixed at 400px while remaining space is be split between left and right divs. With jQuery you can do

```
function calc() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var rem = ww - $('.div2').width();
    $('.div1, .div3').css('width', rem / 2);
}
calc();
$(window).resize(calc);
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/M5Ghx/3/

Comment: +1 However I'd be wary of relying on JavaScript to implement basic page layout just in case the browser visting the page has JavaScript disabled or is running on a machine so slow that it the user would received the HTMl, see the page, then have the JavaScript kick in and re-assemble the page layout. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784/should-you-design-websites-that-require-javascript-in-this-day-age/62830#62830) answer to a similar question sums up the limitations pretty well.

Comment: No one have JavaScript disabled unless unless the person is still living in the ancient ages. Every site on the web uses javaScript in one way or the other.

Comment: Not everyone has JavaScript enabled. Some sysadmins will disable JS on company computers simply so they don't have to worry about security risks, some people using older computers will have it disabled so they can speed up their browser, mobiles with limited processing power won't use it. JS should be used as a progressive enhancement to website behaviour and not rely on it. I'm going to link to another answer on from [this website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373818/whats-with-those-do-not-use-javascript-people/417533#417533) which again sums it up quite well.

Comment: Don't look at 1% of people who turns it off because they want to speeds up there browsing. They must have very slow connection and computer from the stone age.  This is crazy. You disconnect yourself from the web if you have it off. Happy HTML viewing.

Comment: Missing the point. I'm saying you shouldn't assume that everyone uses the technology because those who don't would otherwise be left in the dark. Look at it this way: not every browser will have JavaScript enabled even if it's a small percentage however every browser will be capable of rendering HTML & CSS so there is no risk in using HTML & CSS for page layout. There is however a small risk in relying on JavaScript for site layout. If a bank gets 1 million online users and whose site relies on JavaScript, it's possible 10k wouldn't have JS. They'd go elsewhere and the bank would loose money.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you wanted to avoid using javascript, would be to give the center div an absolute position and create two divs to use as buffers within the left and right divs:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align:center">
    <div style="width:50%; height: 50px; float:left">
        <div style="width:250px; height: 50px; float:right"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; position:absolute; left:0; right:0; width: 500px;height:50px;"></div>
    <div style="width:50%; height: 50px; float:right">
        <div style="width:250px; height: 50px; float:left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about Mozilla and WebKit, then you should look in to using the Flexible Box Model:

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

That will solve all your centering issues in pure CSS. Just be sure to read the docs and play around with the different options so that you understand how it works.